# how to make stanford.nlp.process.DocumentPreprocessor faster?

Tags: stanford-nlp

Now I have about 700000 files to token and split sentences, and I find the stanford.nlp.process.DocumentPreprocessor and satisfy my demand.
  But I found that DocumentPreprocessor seems not to support -ioFileList argument(the PTBTokenizer support it), so I have to solve the file one by one, although I use the multiprocessing in python, it's so slow.
  I want make DocumentPreprocessor be faster, is there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you start up a Stanford CoreNLP server, then issue requests in Python.

This is a good Python library for doing this:

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/python-stanford-corenlp

You should be able to set up a pipeline, with just `tokenize,ssplit`, so there is no need to use the DocumentPreprocessor class.